# How to install Mesa from source?

Tags: apt, 18.04, radeon, mesa

How to install Mesa from source code in Ubuntu 18.04?
I downloaded *mesa-18.1.3.tar.xz* from here ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/ then extracted it, then in the directory with the sources did the following.

```
./configure —with-llvm-prefix=/usr/lib/llvm-7// —with-gallium-drivers=radeonsi —with-dri-drivers=radeon
make
sudo make install
```

It was built with no errors.

However *inxi -Fxz* still says I'm using old mesa. Even after reboot. I also tried using `checkinstall` instead of `make install`, but it changed nothing.

```
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Vega [Radeon Vega 8 Mobile] bus-ID: 38:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,radeon)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
       OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.25.0 / 4.17.2-041702-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)
       version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.0-rc5 Direct Render: Yes
```

I want source built mesa to be used instead of one shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: Do `type -a mesa` - perhaps the obsolete `mesa` is in a directory that's earlier in your `PATH` than the newer `mesa`.

Comment: It says command "mesa" isn't found.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such command at all, because Mesa is a library rather than a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --enable-texture-float --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ --with-gallium-drivers=r300,r600,radeonsi,swrast --with-egl-platforms=drm,x11 --enable-glx-tls --enable-shared-glapi --enable-glx --enable-driglx-direct --enable-gles1 --enable-gles2 --enable-gbm --enable-openmax --enable-xa --enable-osmesa --with-radeonsi-llvm-compiler --enable-sysfs --enable-vdpau --enable-xvmc --enable-openmax --enable-nine
make -j5
sudo make install
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use stable and latest Mesa drivers, I suggest you to use PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa
```

Comment: I wanted to test Mesa built with unstable LLVM 7.0 so building from source was the only way to do it. I had random crashes of graphics, but the culprit turn out to be amdgpu, not Mesa. It seems to be fixed in Linux 4.19.

Comment: No longer relevant, VERY outdated, doesn't answer the question and overall a bad idea.